# Discrete Math - p imp q Truth Table

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to understand what imp1 is or how it is used. I'm unable to find further information in my textbook and this is an exercise question.

Question: Provide further motivation for defining p → q to be true when p is false For the first change, we call the resulting operator imp1.

Show that p imp1 q logically equivalent q imp1 p.

(BTW if anyone can direct me to the help section on how to use math symbols in a post I would greatly appreciate it so these questions make more sense).

Thanks all.

[image: Truth Table]

Comment: As a note I understand that they are logically equivalent if the truth tables are identical when showing the converse of p imp q. Again I just need some clarification on what imp is.

Comment: After a little more reading am I correct in concluding that imp is a word phrase used in place of whatever conditional operation was used?

Comment: We have two *connectives* in palce : the *conditional* (or implication) : $\rightarrow$ (written in LaTex : \rightarrow) and the *bi-conditional* (or bi-implication or equivalence) : $\leftrightarrow$ (written in LaTex : \leftrightarrow) . The truth-table for the first one (in case : $p \rightarrow q$) has $FALSE$ only in the row with $p - FALSE$ and $q - TRUE$. The one in your post (called "imp1") is the truth-table for $p \leftrightarrow q$; it has $FALSE$ is the rows where $p$ and $q$ have different truth values.

Comment: For a tutorial on math formulae formatting, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thanks for this breakdown it makes great sense!

Answer (score 0):

Since $p \; imp1 \; q$ is given by the truth table in your question, we see that
\begin{array}{| l | l | l | l |}
\hline
p & q & p \; imp1 \; q & q \; imp1 \; p \\ \hline
T & T & T & T \\ \hline
T & F & F & F \\ \hline
F & T & F & F \\ \hline
F & F & T & T \\ \hline
\end{array}
so $p \; imp1 \; q$ is logically equivalent to $q \; imp1 \; p$. Notice that $p \; imp1 \; q$ is true only when $p$ and $q$ have the same truth value. This operator is usually called *bi-implication* and is written $\leftrightarrow$ and is often read as "if and only if".

Comment: so this is similar to the converse of p → q except we are expressing as you said, "if and only if" both are true or both are false making the proposition true?

Comment: @natur3 the converse of $p \rightarrow q$ is $q \rightarrow p$ which are not logically equivalent. You are right however, that $p \leftrightarrow q$ is logically equivalent to $(p \rightarrow q) \wedge (q \rightarrow p)$, that is, to show bi-implication we need to show implication in both directions. I hope this helped.